# ActiveMQ Artemis topology mistakes

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have a topologic issue working with ActiveMQ Artemis (version 2.27.1).
I work with 3 servers, which on every one there are 2 nodes – master and slave (lets call them A, B, C, A*, B*, C*).
I configured for each master node his replication as the slave node seats next to him (A -> B*, B -> C*, C -> A*).
Here is an example for A & B* `broker.xml` configuration:

Master `broker.xml`:

```xml
<connectors>
    <connector name="Master_A">tcp://[HOSTNAME]:[A_MASTER_PORT]</connector>
    <connector name="Master_B">tcp://[HOSTNAME]:[B_MASTER_PORT]</connector>
    <connector name="Master_C">tcp://[HOSTNAME]:[C_MASTER_PORT]</connector>
    <connector name="Slave_B">tcp://[HOSTNAME]:[B_SLAVE_PORT]</connector>
</connectors>

<cluster-connections>
    <cluster-connection name="artemis-cluster">
          <address></address>
          <connector-ref>A_master_connector</connector-ref>
          <check-period>30000</check-period>
          <connection-ttl>60000</connection-ttl>
          <min-large-message-size>102400</min-large-message-size>
          <call-timeout>30000</call-timeout>
          <retry-interval>500</retry-interval>
          <retry-interval-multiplier>1.0</retry-interval-multiplier>
          <max-retry-interval>5000</max-retry-interval>
          <initial-connect-attempts>-1</initial-connect-attempts>
          <reconnect-attempts>-1</reconnect-attempts>
          <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>
          <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
          <max-hops>1</max-hops>
          <confirmation-window-size>1048576</confirmation-window-size>
          <call-failover-timeout>-1</call-failover-timeout>
          <notification-interval>1000</notification-interval>
          <notification-attempts>2</notification-attempts>
          <static-connectors allow-direct-connections-only="true">
            <connector-ref>Master_B</connector-ref>
            <connector-ref>Master_C</connector-ref>
            <connector-ref>Slave_B</connector-ref>
          </static-connectors>
    </cluster-connection>
</cluster-connections>

<ha-policy>
    <replication>
        <master>
            <check-for-live-server>true</check-for-live-server>
            <vote-on-replication-failure>false</vote-on-replication-failure>
        </master>
    </replication>
</ha-policy>
```

and Slave `broker.xml`:

```xml
<connectors>
    <connector name="Slave_B">tcp://[HOSTNAME]:[B_SLAVE_PORT]</connector>
    <connector name="Master_A">tcp://[HOSTNAME]:[A_MASTER_PORT]</connector>
</connectors>

<cluster-connections>
    <cluster-connection name="artemis-cluster">
          <address></address>
          <connector-ref>B_slave_connector</connector-ref>
          <check-period>30000</check-period>
          <connection-ttl>60000</connection-ttl>
          <min-large-message-size>102400</min-large-message-size>
          <call-timeout>30000</call-timeout>
          <retry-interval>500</retry-interval>
          <retry-interval-multiplier>1.0</retry-interval-multiplier>
          <max-retry-interval>5000</max-retry-interval>
          <initial-connect-attempts>-1</initial-connect-attempts>
          <reconnect-attempts>-1</reconnect-attempts>
          <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>
          <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
          <max-hops>1</max-hops>
          <confirmation-window-size>1048576</confirmation-window-size>
          <call-failover-timeout>-1</call-failover-timeout>
          <notification-interval>1000</notification-interval>
          <notification-attempts>2</notification-attempts>
          <static-connectors allow-direct-connections-only="true">
            <connector-ref> Master_A</connector-ref>
          </static-connectors>
    </cluster-connection>
</cluster-connections>

<ha-policy>
    <replication>
        <slave>
            <max-saved-replicated-journals-size>-1</max-saved-replicated-journals-size>
            <restart-backup>false</restart-backup>
            <allow-failback>true</allow-failback>
            <vote-on-replication-failure>false</vote-on-replication-failure>
        </slave>
    </replication>
</ha-policy>
```

The problem is that I am starting those nodes by the recommended order from the [Artemis documentation][1] – all the masters together, and the all the slaves together. Even tough, the topology is not how I declared, master nodes are connecting to the wrong slave nodes...(that they actually not supposed to have connection to those nodes, because I configured the connections as `only-direct-connections`).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "having a latency"?

Comment: added to the body of the requests explanation about the latency i am having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your configuration isn't appropriate if you want to pair specific primary and backup together. [The documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/ha.html#data-replication) discusses the necessary configuration:

> Within a cluster, there are two ways that a backup server will locate a live server to replicate from, these are:
>
> - `specifying a node group`. You can specify a group of live servers that a backup server can connect to. This is done by configuring `group-name` in either the `master` or the `slave` element of the `broker.xml`. A Backup server will only connect to a live server that shares the same node group name
> - `connecting to any live`. This will be the behaviour if `group-name` is not configured allowing a backup server to connect to any live server

Currently you're aren't specifying `group-name` which means the backup will connect to *any* live broker.

Comment: OK, thank you for your answer! i will add the group-name, which will probably solve my topology issue, and update you if it will affect the latency issue also.

Comment: So my topology issue is solved according to the solution you have suggested, but the latency issue still remained. only when i start my servers in pairs there is no latency.

Comment: This is the problem with asking multiple questions in a single post. Your question should really focus on a single issue otherwise it becomes hard to identify the "correct" answer. I recommend you amend your question to be only about the topology issue and then create a new question about the latency issue.